# FilePond: all JPEG files are uploaded as ".jpg" - why?

Tags: upload, jpeg, filepond, suffix

I've written a small FilePond example (excellent piece of work BTW) but there is one thing that I can't understand:

When I upload, e.g., "foo.JPG" or "foo.jpeg" it is saved as "foo.jpg" on the server.

I would like to keep the file extension, but don't know how to do it.

I've tried the FileRename-plugin but the files are still saved as .jpg.

Comment: Thank you! And thanks for posting your workaround   I think it only does this if you are using image crop / resize plugins, in that case it will check the mime type against an extension table and use the extensions as defined in code.

Comment: Aha, that's why I couldn't find it in the source code!  Well, it seems to be working fine now - still running some tests, but so far so good.  Thank you again for a really nice plugin!

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution.  If anyone is interested I can post complete code, but basically I stored the real filename (e.g., "foo.jpeg") in metadata and extracted it on the PHP server side, and then renamed the temporary file using that name instead.

In FilePond.create:

```
beforeAddFile: (fileItem) => new Promise(resolve => {
    fileItem.setMetadata('true_filename', fileItem.filename);
    resolve(true);
}),
```